# Angular - ngIf condition displays both the data on Initial render

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

In my Angular project where I get data from API and display on frontend. I am using ngIf to display data, if no data is available then `elseNotDone` is displayed.

The problem I am facing is when component reloads, I first see   `No Data available` for few milliseconds and then data is displayed

**How can I make sure else condition is not displayed on initial render?**

```
<section *ngIf="data!== undefined && data.length > 0; else elseNotDone">
  <h2>Amazon Data</h2>
  <div>
  // display data from API
  </div>
</section>
  <ng-template #elseNotDone>
  No Data available
  </ng-template>
```

Comment: That's the timing API call is taking

Comment: I too thought that, anything I can do to overcome this?

Comment: The easiest workaround would be a `loading` variable that's set to `true `when you start fetching your `data` and set back to `false` when it's done fetching. `<div *ngIf="loading">Data is loading</div>`

Comment: @MikeS. This works, I guess I need to add else which displays no data when

Comment: @MikeS.   @Master.Deep please check this code `<div *ngIf="!loading then loggedIn">Data is loading</div>
<ng-template #loggedIn>
<section *ngIf="data !== undefined && data.length > 0;else elseNotDone">
  <h2>Amazon</h2>
  <div>
    //data from api
  </div>
</section>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #elseNotDone>
  No Data available </ng-template>`

Answer (score 0):

This is because the component initializes before the data has arrived. Once the data arrives, the component can then use it.

I would **highly** recommend learning about Angular Resolvers that prevent the component from initializing before the data is available. This allows you to implement things like loaders / spinners / etc, that appear while the data is being fetched.

**EDIT:**
From the Angular documentation:
https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve

Comment: please check this code `<div *ngIf="!loading then loggedIn">Data is loading</div> <ng-template #loggedIn> <section *ngIf="data !== undefined && data.length > 0;else elseNotDone">   <h2>Amazon</h2>   <div>     //data from api   </div> </section> </ng-template> <ng-template #elseNotDone>   No Data available </ng-template>`

Answer (score 0):

Unnecessarily you complicated it:

```
*ngIf="data !== undefined && data.length > 0; else elseNotDone"
```

Change it to:

```
*ngIf="data && data.length > 0; else elseNotDone"
```

For your main problem:
Create a variable `isLoaded` and wrap your code in it:

```
<div *ngIf="isLoaded">
  .... your code...
</div>
```

It will solve your problem to show anything until data is loaded.

Comment: please check this code `<div *ngIf="!loading then loggedIn">Data is loading</div> <ng-template #loggedIn> <section *ngIf="data !== undefined && data.length > 0;else elseNotDone">   <h2>Amazon</h2>   <div>     //data from api   </div> </section> </ng-template> <ng-template #elseNotDone>   No Data available </ng-template>`. I am unable to display `Data is loading`

Comment: Okay but where should I add text `Loading`?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in the ng-container with the isLoaded condition and you should "true" this variable if you get the response from API

```
 <ng-container *ngIf="isLoaded">
    <section *ngIf="data && data.length > 0; else elseNotDone">
      <h2>Amazon Data</h2>
      <div>
        // display data from API
      </div>
    </section>
    <ng-template #elseNotDone>
       No Data available
    </ng-template>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Okay, where should I display text as `Loading` when`isLoaded is true?`

Comment: What I am looking for is to display `Data is loading` till data is retrived from API. If data then dispnay or  display  text `no data `

Comment: You can use `*ngIf="!isLoaded"` in another ng-container to show **Data is loading**